# Jquery data table need to show the blank records at bottom always (any sorting)

Tags: jquery

I am having table with mixed empty,non-empty values if i click the column name sorting will be done, i need blank records at bottom always if i click asc, desc sort what ever i click blank,empty records need to shown in bottom only what i want to do for that please help me any one.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "")
           return 1;
        if(str2 == "")
           return -1;
           return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
    },                   
    "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "")
            return 1;
        if(str2 == "")
            return -1;
            return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
    }
    });
</script>
</head>
                <table id="example" class='dataTable fn dataTableExt oSort' border='1'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Customer</th>
                        <th colspan="2">2016</th>
                        <th colspan="2">2015</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Performance %</th> 
                        <th>Rank</th>
                        <th>Performance %</th> 
                        <th>Rank</th>
                    <tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name1</td>
                        <td>100%</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>77%</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name2</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>70%</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>72%</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name5</td>
                        <td>98%</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name6</td>
                        <td>99%</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>name7</td>
                        <td>71%</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>78%</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script>
            var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 8, //Number of rows
                "bLengthChange": false, //Disable "show 1-n entries"
                bFilter: false, //Disable filter
                bInfo: false,
                columnDefs: [{ "type" : "non-empty-string",targets: [0,4] }],
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ],[ 2, "asc" ]]
            });
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9mobgu8h/3/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're checking if your string is `== ""`.

Are you sure the empty strings aren't null? I would suggest this:

```
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "non-empty-string-asc": function(str1, str2) {
                if ( str1 == null || str1 == "")
                    return 1;
                if ( str2 == null || str2 == "")
                    return -1;
                return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
            },

            "non-empty-string-desc": function(str1, str2) {
                if ( str1 == null || str1 == "")
                    return 1;
                if ( str2 == null || str2 == "")
                    return -1;
                return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
            }
        });
```

Additionally, you're missing the jQuery and DataTable libraries.

Add this at the top of your body:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

If you want the ordering to work for all columns, rather than just the name and rank columns, you need to change the `targets` in this:

```
            var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 8, //Number of rows
                "bLengthChange": false, //Disable "show 1-n entries"
                bFilter: false, //Disable filter
                bInfo: false,
                columnDefs: [{ "type" : "non-empty-string",targets: [0,4] }],
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ],[ 2, "asc" ]]
            });
```

With this:

```
            var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 8, //Number of rows
                "bLengthChange": false, //Disable "show 1-n entries"
                bFilter: false, //Disable filter
                bInfo: false,
                columnDefs: [{ "type" : "non-empty-string",targets: [0,1,2,3,4] }],
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ],[ 2, "asc" ]]
            });
```

Comment: this also not helped me

Comment: Well, please give us more details. What is happening exactly?

Comment: Ascending, descending order sort only working, i need empty records stay in only at bottom for any sort.

Comment: If you order by name or by rank, the order works perfectly. Do you want it to work that way in all columns? I've edited the answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks for your help 
https://jsfiddle.net/9mobgu8h/9/
now empty records came bottom of the table this is ok, but performance values not in the proper order if i click rank its working fine for empty and values. but performance  column empty came bottom of table the values not in the proper order what to do for that to become proper order based on values also.

Comment: That's because you're sorting the value as a string, so it gets sorted in alphabetical order. If you want to sort it as an integer you'll need to define a different sorter and assign it to that column.

Comment: $2,345
$2
$3
$6
$1,000
like this values sorting is not working what i want to do or this
i tried this 
    str1 = str1.replace("$", "");
    str2 = str2.replace("$", ""); 
This will not helped me i didn't get proper sort order

Comment: You have to use something like parseFloat() to turn the string into a number. Simply removing the $ sign doesn't change the datatype.

Comment: Nice. It would have taken me a while digging through the documentation to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, not sure where I found it or I would credit the answer.

```
     jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mystring-asc'] = function (x, y) {
      var retVal;
      x = $.trim(x);
      y = $.trim(y);

      if (x == y) retVal = 0;
      else if (x == "" || x == " ") retVal = 1;
      else if (y == "" || y == " ") retVal = -1;
      else if (x > y) retVal = 1;
      else retVal = -1; // <- this was missing in version 1

      return retVal;
  }
  jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['mystring-desc'] = function (y, x) {
      var retVal;
      x = $.trim(x);
      y = $.trim(y);

      if (x == y) retVal = 0;
      else if (x == "" || x == " ") retVal = -1;
      else if (y == "" || y == " ") retVal = 1;
      else if (x > y) retVal = 1;
      else retVal = -1; // <- this was missing in version 1

      return retVal;
  }
```